# UIScrollView messaging app behaviour

Tags: ios, iphone, user-interface, uiscrollview

I've been wondering how apps like Facebook Messenger, Whatsapp or the Messages app on iOS itself work (from the UI perspective).

I assume they're using a `UIScrollView` and add `UILabel`s at the bottom of view with the message and/or info of the message itself, giving a fixed space between labels, and so on...

Am I right or my approach is completely wrong?

Comment: More likely it is a `UITableView` (which inherits from `UIScrollView`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In iOS6 and above, you have `UICollectionView`, which inherits from `UIScrollView`, but gives you tableview-like cell management without being restricted to one row. For example, both the iOS7 Messages app and the new Facebook Messenger use collection views to implement what you look for.

There are several open-source solution that implement a similar behavior, which you can take a look at for use or ideas. [`THSpringyCollectionView`](https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/THSpringyCollectionView), [JSMessagesViewController](https://github.com/jessesquires/MessagesTableViewController) and others.

Comment: Interesting enough... I'll definitely take a look into these. Thanks a lot!